# Saving and accessing files on a mounted drive in nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, express

I have 3 servers running as a cluster managed by flynn (a bit like heroku) which I can attach a shared drive to so that in theory they all have access to the same files.

However I'm a bit unsure if it's possible to access a mounted drive from my nodejs app to save and access files.

Can anyone shed some light on if this is possible and roughly how I'd go about doing it.

Comment: What platform are you running on?  In general, if the drive is mounted and available to the OS from the command line, then it's certainly available to the file system module in node.js.  Mounted drives may have some different capabilities (such as locking) than local drives, but the data should be accessible from node.js if it the volume is mounted and is available from the command line.

Comment: The servers are Ubuntu Linux and the drive is an NFS mount and I can access it from the command line.

Comment: So, did you have a problem using the NFS path to the file from the fs module in node.js?  It should just work.  This sounds like you're asking a theoretical question without trying it in your own environment.  Questions here should report what you tried and exactly what problems you ran into.

Comment: The thing I can't work out is serving the files to the client and that whats confusing me. So they request example.com/uploads/test.jpg but the files are saved in /mnt/shared/uploads

This is what currently serves my files and I tried adding the mounted path in front but that didn't work which is why I questioned if it was possible.

`get: function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(req.path.substr(1));
    }`

Answer (score 2):

With node.js, your file system path has literally nothing to do with the URLs that your server supports.  node.js servers do not serve ANY files by default (unlike some other servers).

If you want an incoming browser request for `http://example.com/uploads/test.jpg` to read a file from `/mnt/shared/uploads`, then you have to create a web server route handler that includes the incoming path `http://example.com/uploads/test.jpg` and then reads the data from `/mnt/shared/uploads` and writes that data out as the http response.

Depending upon what web server environment you are using, there are helpers to do that mapping.  For example, express has `express.static()` that helps with some auto mapping.  But, the web server by itself does not server any files like this automatically.

So, if what you want is that all incoming requests for `http://example.com/uploads/*` will be read from `/mnt/shared/uploads/*`, then you can use `express.static()` to help you do that like this:

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static("/mnt/shared/uploads"));
```

This will take any path it finds after `/uploads` and look for that path in `/mnt/shared/uploads`.  If found, it will automatically serve the content as static content.

So, it would work like this with the incoming URL shown first and the place `express.static()` would look for a matching file:

```
/uploads/test.jpg       ==> /mnt/shared/uploads/test.jpg
/uploads/bob/test.txt   ==> /mnt/shared/uploads/bob/test.txt
```